# Passing 2 dimensional array to function

Tags: arrays, c, function, pointers, 2d

I am trying to do this with c

```
#include <stdio.h>
int getWordAmount(FILE *file);
void getWords(char names[][]);

int main() {
    FILE *file = fopen("files/country.txt", "a+");
    if(file != NULL) printf("File is opened\n");
    else printf("Error occured in opening file\n");
    int n = getWordAmount(file);
    char names[n][20];
    getWords(names);

    for(int i = 0; i < n; i++) {
        for(int j = 0; names[i][j] != '\0'; j++) {
            printf("%c", names[i][j]);
        }
    }
    return 0;
}

int getWordAmount(FILE *file) {
    char c;
    int charAmount = 0;
    while ((c = getc(file)) != EOF) {
        if((c == ' ')||(c == '\n')) charAmount++;
    }
    return charAmount;
}

void getWords(char names[][]) {
    int i = 0, j = 0, k = 0;
    char temp[20];
    while ((c = getc(file)) != EOF) {
        temp[i++] = c;
        if((c == ' ')||(c == '\n')) {
            i = 0;
            while((temp[i] != ' ')||temp[i] != '\n') {
                names[j][k++] = temp[i++];
            }
            j++;
            i = 0;
        }
    }
}
```

And i am getting this error shown below

> E:\Programming\C Files\files.c:3:20: error: array type has incomplete
> element type 'char[]' 3 | void getWords(char names[][]); | ^~~
> E:\Programming\C Files\files.c:3:20: note: declaration of 'names' as
> multidimensional array must have bounds for all dimensions except the
> first E:\Programming\C Files\files.c: In function 'main':
> E:\Programming\C Files\files.c:11:12: error: type of formal parameter
> 1 is incomplete 11 | getWords(names); | ^ E:\Programming\C
> Files\files.c: At top level: E:\Programming\C Files\files.c:30:20:
> error: array type has incomplete element type 'char[]' 30 | void
> getWords(char names[][]){ | ^ E:\Programming\C Files\files.c:30:20:
> note: declaration of 'names' as multidimensional array must have
> bounds for all dimensions except the first E:\Programming\C
> Files\files.c: In function 'getWords': E:\Programming\C
> Files\files.c:33:11: error: 'c' undeclared (first use in this
> function) 33 | while ((c = getc(file)) != EOF){ | ^ E:\Programming\C
> Files\files.c:33:11: note: each undeclared identifier is reported only
> once for each function it appears in E:\Programming\C
> Files\files.c:33:20: error: 'file' undeclared (first use in this
> function); did you mean 'fileno'? 33 | while ((c = getc(file)) !=
> EOF){ | ^~ | fileno

Here is my country.txt

```
Bangladesh India China Nepal Bhutan
Pakistan Indonesia America Miyanmar
USA North-Korea South-korea Brazil
Argentina
Indonesia Japan Singapur Africa Rassia
```

Comment: You can't declare a formal parameter as `char names[][]`.  The second dimension (more precisely, all but the first) must be specified, or it will not be able to index into the array.  So `char names[][20]` would work (it gets adjusted to `char (*names)[20]`), or you could use a variable dimension size.

Comment: Multidimensional array must have bounds for all dimensions except the first.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As you can see the error, declaration of a multidimensional array must have bounds for all dimensions except the first.
So you can do this (one of the ways and the easiest way for your question):

```c
// in your case the 20 is second dimension
void getWords(char names[][20]) {
    int i = 0, j = 0, k = 0;
    char temp[20];
    while ((c = getc(file)) != EOF) {
        temp[i++] = c;
        if((c == ' ')||(c == '\n')) {
            i = 0;
            while((temp[i] != ' ')||temp[i] != '\n') {
                names[j][k++] = temp[i++];
            }
            j++;
            i = 0;
        }
    }
}
```